# Registered NIB, still getting assertion error when I use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xib, reuseidentifier

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` class that I want to use to create custom table cells. I created the custom table cell's xib as well as its header and implementation files, all called `RTRepairOrderTableCell.m/.h/.xib`.

My issue is that even though I set the reuse identifier of the table cell to `RTRepairOrderTableCell` inside of the .xib file and registered the xib inside of my table view controller, I am still getting assertion errors when it tries to dequeue or create a new cell for use.

Inside of my view (table) controller I have the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Load the nib file
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"RTRepairOrderTableCell"
                                bundle:nil];
    // Register this Nib, which contains the cell
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib
         forCellReuseIdentifier:@"RTRepairOrderTableCell"];    
}
```

There are no errors here and it finishes `viewDidLoad` just fine.

Inside of my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I have the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{       
    RTRepairOrderTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RTRepairOrderTableCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];      
    return cell;
}
```

According to every tutorial I've seen, this should work so long as I have the reuse identifier set properly inside the xib file and I register that xib inside of `viewDidLoad` in the view controller class that will display the table cells, so I am at a loss as to why I am getting

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _dequeueReusableViewOfType:withIdentifier:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.138/UITableView.m:5413
```

Answer (score 10):

Turns out I had a few orphaned `UIImage` objects inside the nib file but outside of the `UITableViewCell` area, so it was throwing errors saying that the `UITableViewCell` needed to be the topmost view.

Comment: Mine was caused by a `UITapGestureRecognizer` in the UITableViewCell nib for similar reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this and it was driving me crazy. But it was my fault. I had set identifier @"Abc" in Nib file and I was registering the same nib file with some other identifie @"Xyz". Removed the identifier from nib, left that part blank and it worked like a champ. :)

Comment: Ahh! This was it for me too.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a rare case, but due to some sloppy copy pasta two different `UITableViewCell` custom classes used in my table had the exact same Identifier specified in the Xib.

Switching one of these cells to have a different Identifier in the Attributes Inspector fixed my Assertion failures.

Answer (score 0):

Check if in your .xib there are no UI component outside main layout:

[Label is not accepted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij87U.png)

In this example, Label is not accepted and cause the exception